# Can't see JSON data - PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

I was trying to read simple content from http://ergast.com/api/f1/drivers/kobayashi.json with a PHP file, but I can't see anything.

```
<?php

$file = file_get_contents('http://ergast.com/api/f1/drivers/vettel.json/');
$data = json_decode($file,true);

echo $data['MRData']['DriverTable']['Drivers']['familyName'];

?>
```

Edit 1:

```
<?php

$file = file_get_contents('http://ergast.com/api/f1/drivers/vettel.json');
$data = json_decode($file,true);

echo $file;
echo $data;
echo $data['MRData']['DriverTable']['Drivers']['0']['familyName'];

?>
```

File is the same, but seems I can't reach file because I can't see anything if I open the file. :(

Comment: Have you tried removing the trailing slash from your url?

Comment: Visiting that URL gives me "Format not found.", so it's only logical you can't read data from something that's not there.

Comment: Yes, you haven't the same URL in your example and in your code

Comment: Its a Forbidden syscall socketcall

Answer (score 0):

Remove the slash and after the driver result is coming in array.

u can check that with print_r debugging option.

```
$file = file_get_contents('http://ergast.com/api/f1/drivers/vettel.json');
$data = json_decode($file,true);
//echo "<pre>";
//print_r($data);
//echo "</pre>";
echo $data['MRData']['DriverTable']['Drivers'][0]['familyName'];
```